# Google News Timeline

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeline

I'd like to kind of recreate Google's News Timeline.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcIsw.png

Can you recommend some suitable JavaScript/Ajax libraries?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to [read over the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get a sense of what types of questions are a good fit, as [the site does not provide recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/173644).

Comment: Also welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to UPVOTE all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And choose/check/accept the best answer to your questions.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot upvote, as I don't have 15 reputation points yet.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Simile Timeline.](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/)

If you like to have a lot of thumbnail images in the timeline, see the [Compact Painter](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/examples/compact-painter/compact-painter.html) version. (Unfortunately, a lot of the images used in the demo have moved, hence the blank thumbnails.)

Disclaimer: I've contributed to it in the past.

Comment: Thank you! Does it also support dynamic loading (using Ajax) while scrolling?

Comment: Yes and no, it loads all the event timing details and titles at start up. But the descriptions and images are only loaded when needed. Plus you can change the library, it's open source.

Comment: Thank you! Well, I am reliant on dynamic loading because of the huge amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Timeline from the CHAP Links Library:

http://almende.github.com/chap-links-library/timeline.html

With this timeline you cannot create a view exactly as in the screenshot you show, but you cn put your items in "boxes". The CHAP Links Timeline is quite flexible easy to use. You can put your own HTML formatted items in the Timeline, and completely tune the css as you like.

Comment: Thank you! Like it better than Simile. Does it also support dynamic loading (using Ajax) while scrolling?

Comment: Oh, and what about vertical scrolling, if there are many items at one point?